# Why does my javascript works in test environment, but not on live site?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the url:

http://scottpandel.com/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: all of your scripts failed to load - check your relative paths.

Comment: (Offtopic) don't ever use BOLD text on hover! (not at least if you don't use CSS: `text-align:center;`)

Comment: Always include the relevant markup and code **in the question itself**, don't just link. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 3):

I am getting 404's on a lot of your http requests for scripts.

- http://scottpandel.com/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js
- http://scottpandel.com/js/plugins.js
- http://scottpandel.com/js/script.js
- http://scottpandel.com/js/jquery.js

Make sure the path is correct and that the source exists.

Comment: +1 just for taking your time to give it a look